# Problem with the callback of auto connect to Bluetooth LE device Ionic v3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, bluetooth-lowenergy

I try to use the auto connect with my Bluetooth LE device via @ionic-native/ble as the code below:

```
this.ble.autoConnect(this.macConnected,function () {
     console.log("Connect");
},function () {
      console.log("Disconnect");
});
```

My device seem like the bluetooth state is not stable sometime it disconnect and connect again, I can see how it connected or disconnected by the indicate led on the device. But when I look on the console I found that the connect callback is only call at the first time connect, the disconnect callback is called several time but after that when it reconnect again it not callback the function connect. As you can see the picture below[image]
I have to update the connection state in the app, due to this situation the state will always be Disconnected, any one have any suggestion for me ?

Comment: Seems to be a bug in that case in their library. Have you filled an issue report?

Comment: I will do it right now, thank for your suggestion